# Angular proxy.conf

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, http-proxy

I'm trying to send all my requests from `localhost:4200` to `localhost:3000` but I can't achieve what I want. 
My `Node.js` server uses `localhost:3000/login` and `localhost:3000/register`.
In the front end, I do

```
http.post('/login', {whatever})
```

but I cant get the request to my server without sending it to `http://localhost:3000/login`.
Here is my `proxy.conf.json`

```
{
  "/login": { // I tried with "*" and ""
  "target": "http://localhost:3000",
  "secure": false,
  "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

I want all the requests I do to go to `localhost:3000`. 
Everywhere I see that people put `/api` prefix, but this will send it to `localhost:3000/api/login`and I want just `localhost:3000/login`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mine looks like this /ProjectREST is the backend prefix to all URL ie its the rootProject.name(in graddle) of my backend server.

```
{
  "/ProjectREST": {
     "target":  {
       "host": "localhost",
       "protocol": "http:",
       "port": 8090
     },
     "secure": false,
     "changeOrigin": true,
     "logLevel": "debug"
   }
 }
```

I access the server via "/ProjectREST/register" requests.

Comment: I tried to avoid `ProjectREST` part. Is this the usual way things are done? If so I will add something like this to my routes.

Comment: yes, think about it, if you had two back end project under the same tomcat server for example, how would it tell the difference between project1 and project2  url mapping? that's why it use the projectName in the URL.